# Largest $b_2$ with nef $K_X$ and $b_3=0$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

What is the largest known second Betti number of a smooth projective threefold with nef canonical divisor and vanishing third Betti number?

Comment: I might be missing something, but I think arbitrary products of K3 surfaces give arbitrarily high second Betti number, whilst having vanishing third Betti number, and the canonical line bundle is still trivial, so in particular nef.

Comment: @pbelmans That is correct.

Comment: Sorry, I read "variety" instead of "threefold", so I did miss something important in the statement of the question! We can delete these comments if you want, they serve no real purpose after all.

Comment: @pblemans It does serve a purpose, If you now take a complete intersection in your product of K3's, you get that for fourfolds of this type $b_2$ is unbounded.

Comment: @DonuArapura Do you get nef canonical divisor that way?

Comment: @pbelmans You didn't misread. I changed the question after your comment.

Comment: @virkkunen Yes, if $K_X$ is nef, then $K_Y= (K_X+Y)|_Y$ is nef if $Y\subset X$ is an ample divisor.

Comment: @DonuArapura OK thank you.

Comment: @virkkunen I guess you are new to Mathoverflow. But it is not good form to change the question after people give answers (even in comments).

Comment: @DonuArapura It is OK if the answers make you realize your formulation was not quite right, they are a "trivial counterexample" or something. This can be a bit subjective. For me, this is one of the main reasons to answer in the comments - I do this when I think the asker will likely want to edit their question in response.

Comment: @WillSawin OK, fair enough. In this case, the stable form of the question was the most interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** This example was wrong (it has $b_3\neq 0$). In fact, such a threefold does not exist: this follows from my answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/389402/simply-connected-threefold-with-nef-k-x-and-b-3-0/389410#389410) (note that $b_3= 0$ implies $b_1= 0$ by Lefschetz theorem).

Comment: What is $\pi_1$ of your example?

Comment: If $S$ is simply connected (e.g. a complete intersection), it is $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: But then $b_3\neq 0$?

Comment: Sorry, I was too hasty. $\pi _1$ is a semi-direct product of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ by $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: In case anyone else wonders, the $b_3$ of your original example of $(S \times E)/ (\sigma, \pm 1)$ for a surface $S$ with $b_1=0$ and a fixed-point free-involution $\sigma$ would have been  $2(b_2(S) - b_2(S^\Sigma))$. This is because $H^3( S \times E) = H^2(S ) \otimes H^1(E)$ by K\"unneth. and then the involution acts by $-1$ on $H^1(E)$ so we pick up the $-1$ eigenspace on $H^2(S)$. By Lefschetz we have $\operatorname{tr} (\sigma, H^2 ( S) )=-2$ so this is indeed positive - in fact it's $b_2(S)+2$.